# Android emulator freeze my whole system when it can't connect to adb daemon

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I recently changed my computer and took the opportunity to move from Mageia to Fedora. But I can't do any Android development anymore because, as stated in the title, starting *any* AVD makes the whole system to freeze (screen, mouse and keybord) if the AVD can't connect to adb daemon. The only thing I can do is hard shutdown.

The problem here is adb daemon is always started when I try to launch an AVD as the service is enabled by default, so that shouldn't happen.

What I've been able to collect so far is a few logs in a file by lauching the emulator from command-line. All it says before freezing is:

> emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
> emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

*But*, if I manually restart the adb service just before lauching the AVD, I don't experience the freeze. Instead, I get the following errors before the AVD crashes:

> cannot add library .../android-sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
> added library .../android-sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
> cannot add library .../android-sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: full

My best guess here is there's something bad going on with the graphic card. Something I am seemingly the only one to exprerience as I couldn't find any relevant result on internet. I must mention here that I've already tried to run several AVDs in multiple API versions, both software and hardware rendered graphics and I always get the same result.

My system configuration is

- AMD Ryzen 9
- Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 using the Nouveau drivers
- kernel 5.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever stumbles upon this question facing the same issue than me, that was solved by getting rid of the Nouveau drivers and using Nvidia's proprietary drivers. A handful of other disturbing bugs on my computer were solved by doing just that.

I really don't understand why some Linux distribution still strongly advise to use the Nouveau drivers over Nvidia'as when they have a such a really poor support of the GPUs...